# Paginate list mixin in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a mixin:

```
class GroupListMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GroupListMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['group_list'] = Group.objects.all()
        return context
```

which I use in many other views. My problem is that I want to paginate `group_list`.

I've tried inheriting from `django.views.generic.list.BaseListView` but I get the error `'UserUpdateView' object has no attribute 'object'` when I combine `GroupListMixin` with `UserUpdateView`.

Is it not possible to use `BaseListView` as a mixin with other views?

Comment: Could you post more of your UserUpdateView?

Comment: I use it with many different views. It could also be with `UserDetailView` which is just `class UserDetailView(GroupListMixin, DetailView): model = User`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can elegantly mix DetailView and BaseListView together. It might be simplest to just make your own mixin with the appropriate paginate methods, and then use it on your group_list.